# MS Excel - remove specific character when leaving cell?

Tags: excel

I've got users entering MAC Addresses in cells and they are using various styles:

```
xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx
xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

So I'm looking at find a way to sanitise this so the MAC address always appears the same regardless of how they enter it. I'd like it to look like `xxxxxxxxxxxx`

If I'm entering the MAC address in a cell how do I remove the `-:.` characters from that cell and leave just the 'cleaned' address ?

I did think about `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""),":","")` but I'm not sure how to apply it to the cell.

Can someone advise please.
Thanks

Comment: You will need vba in a Worksheet_Change event.  Formula cannot change the data in the cell in which the user places the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim MyCol As String, MyRange As Range, rng As Range, r As Range
    MyCol = "A"
    Set MyRange = Range(MyCol & ":" & MyCol)
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, MyRange)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In rng
            x = r.Value
            x = Replace(x, "-", "")
            x = Replace(x, ":", "")
            x = Replace(x, ".", "")
            r.Value = x
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

It will automatically remove the unwanted characters.
The code is for column **A**. *(it does for column **A** cells what your formula does.)*

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 1):

Well, you might try Data Validation on the cells where they enter the mac address, this limits what they can enter, may be an easier option than changing after. You can also have an input message reminding them of the required format:

[image]

Which gives:

[image]

[image]

[image]